# systemd not finding my .service file

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, steam, lib, systemctl

systemd not finding my .service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Game Server
[Service]
Type=simple
User=steam
Group=steam
Restart=on-failure
ExecStop=killall -TERM srcds_linux
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Its saved under `/lib/systemd/system/game.service`

When I `systemctl start csgo.service` it says `Unit csgo.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status csgo.service' for details.`

i'v done `systemctl --system daemon-reload` and it still is not working,
any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

The game.service should be placed in /etc/systemd/system/game.service

Answer (score 0):

If you name your service file game.service, then it should be activated using `systemctl start game.service`

Another advice : put all services files created by you inside /etc/system/system /lib/systemd/system is reserved for system units.

Then do a `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl start game.service`